# Intellij Import maven modules recursively is broken Intellij 11 and 12 EAP?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij 11 it worked occasionally but was the behavior was highly unreliable.

The problem is that if you check "Search recursively..." then it appears to search, but fails to list all, but for some reason, it might work at occasion, although I am unsure when. So I am able to import my modules, other than manually one by one.

It appears as if there is a bug with the recursive scanner, which seems to scan all, but fails to list all found...

Also reported on: 
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93483

Is there a way around this!?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug specific to your environment, attach `idea.log` to the reported issue so that we can find out why it happens (`Help` | `Reveal Log in ...`).

[This case](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64132#comment=27-380070) may be related.